# using $mysql used in class in all functions

Tags: php

I have a small question regarding the use of Global.
I downloaded a Query class, and changed/added several things including switched to mysqli, finally there is some different roles that need to link mysql to another page with variable settings.

Finally the functions of the class, need to call the variable $ mysqli, so I have to declare at the start of the function global $mysqli;

There is a way to declare this variable for all functions at once page?

Comment: Using `global` is to be avoided if possible. It's better to pass your `$mysqli` variable into the class in the constructor. You can't do this once for all pages - the connection will need to be set up on each new page.

Comment: The class should have a class member for holding mysqli

Comment: @MikeW if I do not put in all the global functions of the class, php will return an error that the variable is not known.

Comment: @PatrickEvans class has several functions, this is the class: http://code.google.com/p/class-query/
I adapted to mysqli are many queries you need to link, could understand?

Comment: @moderadorkl25 I misunderstood your wording. You will need to declare the variable `global` in every method, but as I said, you shouldn't do it this way. You should pass the object in as a parameter to the constructor. Your methods should refer to `$this->mysqli`.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't use `global` for this. You should pass the `$mysqli` object in as a parameter to the constructor ad refer to `$this->mysqli` from within your methods.

For example:

```
class myDb {

private $mysqli;

function __construct($mysqli) {
  $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
}

function queryDb($query) {
    return $this->mysqli->query($query);
}
}
```